Python (false output in tiny alarm project)
I've basically made an alarm without using the playsound library, and the timer is not working properly. I used ANSI escape codes, but they messed up the timer.
import time

Clear = "\033[2J"
Clear_and_return = "\033[H"

def alarm(seconds):
    time_elapsed = 0
    print(Clear)
    while time_elapsed < seconds:
        time.sleep(1)
        time_elapsed += 1

        time_left = seconds - time_elapsed
        min_left = time_left // 60
        sec_left = time_left % 60

        print(f"{Clear_and_return} Time left till alarm: {min_left:02d}:{sec_left:02d}")

minutes = int(input("Minutes: "))
seconds = int(input("Seconds: "))

alarm(minutes * 60 + seconds)

The program runs without errors, but the timer doesn't show up until it reaches 00:00.

I can't replicate the problem. What OS are you working on? What terminal are you using?
